# Hot to convert string into date in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have a string

```
date = 25 aug 18
```

is there any way to convert this into date time format,

```
date = 25 August 2018
```

Comment: Please go through this link for your [help](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
echo  date('d F Y', strtotime("25 aug 2018")). "\n";
```

output: https://3v4l.org/2T9NF

refer:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. But when I do `date('d F Y', strtotime('08/10/2018'));` , it shows me 10 August 2018 instead of showing 08 October 2018? Why is that?

Comment: strtotime uses american date notations i.e. mm/dd/yyyy when the input string is of the format **/**/****

Comment: Now that you are experimenting with date formats, have a look at my answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058697/date-formatting-in-php-for-string-with-am-and-pm/52059182#52059182 it shows how to use different date formats.

Comment: Also, a humble request to approve and upvote the answers.