# Date Formatting in php for string with AM and PM

Tags: php, mysql

Iam trying to change the date format from `08-28-2018 06:33 PM` to `2018-07-23 18:33:00` in order to store it in mysql timestamp but not able to do it in PHP

Comment: Show your attempt

Comment: How do you get 18:35:18 from 18:33?

Answer (score 2):

Refer:

**DateTime::createFromFormat**: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

**DateTime::format**: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$datestring = "08-28-2018 06:33 PM";
$input_format = "m-d-Y h:i A";
$output_format = 'Y-m-d G:i';
$date =  DateTime::createFromFormat($input_format, $datestring);

echo  $date->format($output_format). "\n"; //output 2018-08-28 18:33
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/ajfJk

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', "08-28-2018 06:33 PM")));
```

> **Note**: *Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking
>   at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and
>   the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.*

Source [Link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Here is working [code](https://eval.in/1051406).

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class :

```
// Creating from actual format
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y h:i A', '08-28-2018 06:33 PM');

// Output: 2018-08-28 18:33:00
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

the `A` in the format is for uppercase AM/PM ([see date parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters)).

- [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)
- [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Answer (score -1):

To change 08-28-2018 06:33 PM to 2018-07-23 18:33:00 This is the small and easy solution ever due to php builtin date function.

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('08-28-2018 06:33'));
```

Result will show you like this

```
 2018-07-23 18:33:00
```

Comment: No, this outputs `1970-01-01 01:00:00`